# Using fsharp-typeclasses to make a function that works on arbitrary monads

Tags: haskell, f#, monads, typeclass, fsharp-typeclasses

I'm trying to implement `composM` from the paper [*A pattern for almost compositional functions*](http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/local_75172.pdf) which accepts an arbitray monad and works on it. In Haskell the code would be:

```
data Expr =
    | Var String
    | Abs String Expr

composExprM :: (Monad m) => (Expr -> m Expr) -> Expr -> m Expr
composExprM f e =
    case e of
        Abs n e -> f e >>= (\e' -> return $ Abs n e')
        _       -> return e
```

I tried using [fsharp-typeclasses](https://code.google.com/p/fsharp-typeclasses/) with the code below:

```
type Expr =
    | Var of string
    | Abs of string * Expr

let rec composExprM f e = match e with
    | Abs (n, e) -> f e >>= (fun e' -> return' <| Abs (n, e'))
    | Var _      -> return' e
```

But I get type inference errors:

```
> Could not resolve the ambiguity inherent in the use of the operator 'instance' at or near this program point. Consider using type annotations to resolve the ambiguity.

> Type constraint mismatch when applying the default type 'obj' for a type inference variable. No overloads match for method 'instance'. The available overloads are shown below (or in the Error List window). Consider adding further type constraints

> Possible overload: 'static member Return.instance : _Monad:Return * Maybe<'a> -> ('a -> Maybe<'a>)'. Type constraint mismatch. The type 
      obj    
  is not compatible with type
    Maybe<'a>    
  The type 'obj' is not compatible with the type 'Maybe<'a>'.

> etc.....
```

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible with fsharp-typeclasses? Or do I have to restrict the function to only use a specific monad?

Comment: Yup, you're right. Fixed it (I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that polymorphic functions using this technique should be inline, that's where the "magic" resides.

So, just add the `inline` keyword after `let rec` and it will compile.

Please let me know if the function behaves as expected. I will have a look at that paper later.

In the samples you will find many functions defined to work with any Monad.
That was the main motivation when I started this project.

Comment: Fantastic, that worked! Thanks for making the project by the way :)

Comment: You will probably have to remove `rec` to get `inline` to work - inline recursive functions can't possibly work.

Comment: @John: You're right, there was no need for it to be recursive anyway.

Comment: @John - You're right, but note that you can do something like `let inline f x = let rec f' x' = ... f' ... in f' x` if necessary.